# Image Upload via AJAX - How to pass file name to server ?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to upload an image to the webserver using AJAX, but am unable to pass the file name and path to the PHP script on the server side.

This is the HTML with the JavaScript (ImageUpload01.php) which calls the PHP :

Please do not pay much attention to lines in bold (**....**) as those are the scripts that I wrote for testing and did not work.

The same program I wrote to upload images without the use of AJAX and it DID WORK. 
And also, I did the exact same logic using AJAX to retrieve database record upon sending a customer ID and it also worked. But image upload in AJAX is giving me problems (just because I don't know how to pass the file name/path

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
        <title>Image Upload</title>

        <script>        
            function showThumbnail(str)
            {
                var xmlhttp;  
                **alert(str);**
                **var params = "q=" + $_FILES['file']['name'];**
                if (str==="")
                  {
                  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                  return;
                  }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }

                xmlhttp.open("POST","RunImageUpload01.php",true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");                

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);    
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200)
                    {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                  };
                xmlhttp.send(params);
            }
        </script>        



    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        ?>

        <form action="" > 
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return showThumbnail(file.value);" />
        </form>        


        <div id="txtHint">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

PHP Script on the server side (RunImageUpload01.php)

```
<?php
**$pName = $_POST['q'];**
$moved = move_uploaded_file($pName, "/var/www/vhosts/mywebsiteURL.com/store/mytest/images/temp/" . $pName);

                        if ($moved) {
                            echo "Success"
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "You fool, failure"
                        }

?>
```

Please help me, I prefer JavaScript instead of JQuery.

thanks,

Isaac

Comment: All 3 of the provided answers are either completely wrong, or mostly wrong.  Your should be using FormData to send files in modern browsers, and fall back to submitting a  form that targets a hidden iframe for older browsers.  In both cases, a multipart encoded request will be sent.  The multipart boundary that contains the file will always contain a filename parameter, which you can parse server-side.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? This won't work with older browsers (IE). I know you mentioned that you prefer vanilla javascript, but if you have the option to use jquery, have a look at this plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload. It does all sorts of workarounds and hacks for you to make it work with all browsers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: This is true. The first version of XHR is not widely supported by all browsers. It does answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

The file name cannot be passed together with the file itself. Instead, read the filename with Javascript (from the `file` input element) and send it as a separate `input type="hidden"` element.

By the way, your form element should contain the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, otherwise there will probably be a problem with the file transmission.

Comment: The name will always be passed with the file itself, automatically, as a field in the file's multipart boundary.

Answer (score -1):

Use XHR2 to do it as an alternative to jQuery.

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-formdata-interface

The original XMLHttpRequest does not properly support multipart data.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.  jQuery will using XHR2 where supported.

Comment: Everyone doesn't want to use jQuery... You can use the XHR2 alone without the overhead... WHy did you come in and downvote when we all try to help.

Comment: Thank you, I will try all the answers tonight. Thanks a lot and really appreciated for your time.